# Will an OSPF route in IOS be preferred over a static route? (It isn't Floating Static)

Tags: cisco-ios, ospf, route

[image: Network Topology]

For the network topology attached in the image, a static route is configured with `ip route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.252 Ethernet0/0`. Referring to the Topology and the output from the `show ip route` command, the OSPF route has the prefix /30. And, the configured static route has a prefix /29.

Considering IOS's routing priorities, I think **despite OSPF having a higher AD than static** and not configuring a floating static, the OSPF route would be preferred over the static one because the **OSPF route is more specific with a prefix /30 as compared to the less specific static route with prefix /29**.

However, the source of this question doesn't talk about the prefix length but just says OSPF has an AD that's greater than a static route's AD and hence, the static route would be preferred!

The question has the following options (It's multiple choice):

A) The gateway of last resort will be the Eth0/0 interface on R1
B) Routing Loops or performance problems will occur as R1 points back to itself
C) ***Static Route will be used as a backup if OSPF goes down***
D) **The OSPF route will be replaced by the static route**

As I explained earlier, I think Option C is right (despite not configuring a floating static). But, the original source of the question states Option D as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

252 is a /30.

Static routes have a higher preference than dynamic routes (by default, as in the example.) If you don't want that, set the metric for the static route higher than the dynamic route.

> Static routes have a default administrative distance of 1. A router
> prefers a static route to a dynamic route because the router considers
> a route with a low number to be the shortest. If you want a dynamic
> route to override a static route, you can specify an administrative
> distance for the static route. For example, if you have two dynamic
> routes with an administrative distance of 120, you would specify an
> administrative distance that is greater than 120 for the static route
> if you want the dynamic route to override the static route.

[Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/unicast/503_u1_2/nexus3000_unicast_config_gd_503_u1_2/l3_route.html)

(See Also: [Configure Route Selection for Routers](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/enhanced-interior-gateway-routing-protocol-eigrp/8651-21.html)

Comment: Note: very old IOS (that no one should ever see again) may prefer static no matter what.

Comment: 252 is /30. That's what I did wrong! And yes, Static Routes do have preference over Dynamic ones. Thanks!